# Ubuntu software issue

Tags: software-center, 22.10, snap-store

After a fresh install of Ubuntu 22.10. Ubuntu Software opened normal after the install, but since yesterday when I try to open Ubuntu software a separate Snap-store icon opens in my dock.
Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: Don't know what happened but the issue is suddenly gone